# Tools or scripts for tracking a stolen or lost Mac?

Tags: software, script

Actually I do use [the prey project](http://preyproject.com/) but was wondering about other tools or scripts one could use to find back information about a lost/stolen Mac.

With features like:
-Getting the ip address or any other localization information.
-Triggering the webcam remotely.
-Protect/destroy personal files remotely

Comment: Didn't know about Prey; thanks for mentioning it. Their tagline "Silent but deadly" sure is attention-getting!

Comment: I’m curious, what is that you don’t like about Prey?

Comment: @Martin, Nothing wrong with prey, just reached the limit of the freemium and wondering what else exist. And curious if I could learn from scripts how to achieve similar functionalities.

Comment: thanks for the info, I was just curious. It seems like a nice service for an Open Source app.

Answer (score 2):

One of the more popular ones is [Lojack](http://www.absolute.com/en/lojackforlaptops/home.aspx), a pretty well-respected software program for both Mac and Windows.

Comment: ...and for cars.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Undercover](http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/mac/): it does all that you need, and more (simulating hardware failure, etc.).

Their [recovery stories](http://www.orbicule.com/undercover/mac/recovery.html) section is quite encouraging, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable writing your own script, it is very easy to make a LaunchAgent that uses curl to check for a file on a site you maintain. Web logs now show you the IP. If you put commands in that file, the script on the computer can take action based on those commands.

[isightcapture](http://www.intergalactic.de/pages/iSight.html) can be used to take images from the camera, and `screencapture` of the desktop (showing email accounts of the unauthorized users).

And of course DropBox. If you keep your important documents there, then you can easily delete them. If you want to transfer images from iSight or screencapture off, you can do so. If you want to transfer images on, or upload scripts that a local agent will run, etc, you can do all that very easily.

[MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) could be used to take a screenshot and an iSight image each and every time the computer wakes up or changes network, and email those images (along with IP) to an email account, which you only need to check if you don't know where or who is using the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw a couple more track-spy-recover products into the list: [BAK2u's Phoenix Anti-theft](http://www.bak2u.com/mac.php) and [GadgetTrak](http://www.gadgettrak.com/products/laptop/).  I have no experience with either, so you'll have to make your own judgements.